# Z Transform How to Handle the Inital Condition

Tags: z-transform

I have a question about the Z transform Z{x[k+1]} = X(z)*z^1. How do I account for the initial condition? In continuous systems, the analogous situation is L{x'(t)} = s*X(s) -x(0). I have a equation from a state space equation,
x[k+1] = (I+TA)x[k] where x[0] = 1. I want to find a closed loop solution for x[k] =?. Normally, I would take the Z transform and solve for X(z) and then convert back. However, the Z transform is not taking into account the initial condition and is resulting in a wrong answer.

Comment: Isn't your first line incorrect. The z transform of x[k+1] is going to involve Z\$^{-k}\$

Comment: @Andyaka Well, if you advance 'k' samples, lets say x[n+k]; the z-transform is $$Z^k X(z)$$

Comment: I actually just found a website, I think might have solved my issue. There Z table has the initial condition. http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/ZTransformIntroMod.html

Comment: @bud you are quite within your rights to answer your own question and mark it as the accepted answer should nobody else have a better answer.

Comment: In fact, we encourage it, because if there's no answer, the question will keep getting raised to the front page until somebody does answer.

Comment: Sure thing. How do you use Mathjax in this forum to use the nice formatted type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Z-transform table on this website

[Z-Transform Table Section 9.2](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/ZTransformIntroMod.html)

[image]

The forward tap, item # 7, has the initial condition, which means for a zero input response, x[k] can be calculated to account for the initial condition in the z domain.

In this case, I was trying to calculate: Z{x[k+1] = (I+TA)x[k]}.

yields-> z(X(Z) - x(0)) = (I+TA)X(Z)

Solving for X(Z) = z*x(0) / [z-(I+TA)]

Solving x[k] = Z^-1{X(Z)} = x(0) * (1+TA)^k